# Використання дієслів у минулому часі в контексті речення у майбутньому часі

Tags: вживання-слів, дієслова, дієвідмінювання

У львівський області неодноразово чув випадки, коли в контексті майбутнього часу використовуються слова у минулому. Приклад такого застосування можна почути в кліпі (без цензури) до пісні "Павук" співака Дзідзьо на [56 секунді кліпу](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t75LgtttJXY):

> ... чекай продамо, заробимо гроші та й будем **їли**!

або в тому самому кліпі пізніше на 01:39:

> ... люди не **будуть** в тебе **купляли** ...

Чи є це широко застосована форма використання чи звичайний діалект? І яке в нього походження?

Comment: Поправив теги, тому що йдеться не про етимологію, а про часи дієслів.

Comment: Ще приклад: [Бо як збрешеш, то, їй-богу, / Не за шию, а за ногу / Будеш висів на гілли! (Іван Франко, «Лис Микита», пісня п'ята)](http://poetyka.uazone.net/default/pages.phtml?place=franko&page=mykyta05).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Правопис української мови:](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil2.htm#par80p8)

> - Майбутній час дієслів *недоконаного виду* вживається в таких формах:
>
>   1. **особові форми допоміжного дієслова бути** — буду, будеш, буде, будемо (зрідка будем), будете, будуть **+ інфінітив**: буду писати, будете ходити;
>   2. **інфінітив + скорочені особові форми колишнього дієслова яти (иму...)** — -му, -меш, -ме, -мемо (зрідка -мем), -мете, -муть, що стали дієслівними закінченнями, злившись з інфінітивом: пектиму, пектимеш, пектиме, пектимемо (зрідка пектимем), пектимете, пектимуть.
> - Майбутній час дієслів *доконаного виду* вживається в таких формах:
>
>   1. **префікс + теперішній час**: зроблю, напишу;
>   2. **деякі безпрефіксні дієслова доконаного виду із закінченням теперішнього часу (найчастіше зі значенням одноразової дії)**: гримну, ляжу, пущу, стукну.

---

Ніщо не підходить, хоча дуже наближено до першого підпункту першого пункт, тут: **особові форми допоміжного дієслова бути + минулий час**.

Не можу ручатись за правдивість, але мені здається, що це не широко застосована форма, а штибу *ополячення* чи *розділенність*, з якого може бути і діалект, бо якраз у поляків використовуються два рівномірні варіанти [майбутнього часу:](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czas_przysz%C5%82y) таке саме як у нас і про що тут ми мовимо.

---

Хоча, це все, звісно, походить ще від прасловʼянської мови, яка в свою чергу походить від індоєвропейської, бо подібні стуктури [збереглися](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_verb#Indo-European_languages) і в більшості романских й словʼянских мовах. Отже, [третій спосіб:](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D1%94%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE#%D0%86%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D1%8F)

> Майбутній час міг утворюватися трьома способами.
>
> **Перший** — з використанням особових форм дієслів н*ачѧти, хотѣти, стати* й інфінітива смислового дієслова *(станѫ писати, начьнѫ писати)*.
>
> **Другий спосіб** полягав у використанні форм дієслова имати з інфінітивом *(имѫ писати)*, причому допоміжне дієслово могло стояти і після смислового *(писати имѫ)*.
>
> Від нього походить сучасна складна форма майбутнього часу, особові закінчення якої пов'язані з архаїчними формами дієслова *мати*:
>
> > я писати иму → я писатиму
> >     
> > ти писати имеш → ти писатимеш
> >     
> > він писати име → він писатиме тощо
>
> Але роздільне вживання допоміжного і смислового дієслів **трапляється досі** в деяких західноукраїнських діалектах *(меш ходити, ме ся вмивати)*.
>
> **Третій** — за допомогою допоміжного дієслова *быти* і l-дієприкметника *(бѫдѫ писалъ)*.
>
> Ця форма збереглася в південно-західних діалектах *(буду рубав дрова)*.
>
> А в сучасній літературній мові дієприкметник змінив інфінітив *(буду писати, буду рубати)*.

Comment: До речі, якщо зустрінете штибу цього: _Може, іменно тобі **ся вдасть** до цілі доплисти! [(фрагмент з «Човен» Івана Франка)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcuGvcQfrbA&feature=youtu.be)._ То тут подібна ситуація, поляки завше викироствують **ся** окремо від дієслова. Правда, цей варіант у нас зустрічається частіше й не тільки на Заході. Наприклад, інколи цим прийомом також користувався Шевченко.

Comment: Цікаве зауваження, бо я збирався ставити друге питяння щодо "ся", а точні ше його трансформованного варіанту "сі". Я здогадувався, що це вплив польської мови, але тепер буду знати напевно.

Comment: Додав також загальне походження.

Comment: Також було би доречно запитати, як це так, що у поляків *ся* окремо, а в нас ні? Схоже, що за остані часи Київської Русі чи пізніше — за часи ВКЛ було «поєднання», бо майже всі мови, включно литовської, мають вже «поєданані» зворотні дієслова.

Comment: Мені здається, що перша половина відповіді — взагалі зайва. Адже автор не запитував про усі форми майбутнього часу, а про одну конкретну — *буду* + дієслово у минулому часі.

Comment: Можливо я чогось не зрозумів, але це відповідь на перше питання, що це не є широко застосованою формою, а діалект й причина його існування. Друга частина — походження.

Answer (score 9):

Форма часу, про яку йдеться, називається ***передмайбутній час***, лат. *futurum exactum*.
Він позначає дію, явище або подію, про яку очікується або планується, що на якийсь момент у майбутньому вона буде виконаною. Тобто, ми дивимося у майбутнє і звідти стверджуємо, що подія відбулася (перфект) або відбувалася (імперфект).

В українських західних діалектах/говірках (Галичина, Поділля, Буковина, Покуття) *futurum exactum* формується за допомогою сполучення форм *«буду, будеш, буде»* тощо з формою минулого часу головного дієслова: *буду ходив, будеш робив, буде знала, будемо несли, будуть співали* тощо. У літературній мові такі сполуки не вживаються (або мені не вдалося знайти).

> *Дівчинонько мила, що **будеш робила** на Вкраїні далекій? // **Буду** хусти **прала**, зеленого жита **жала*** — Народна пісня;
>   *Гнів **буде** як грім **гримів*** — Б. Лепкий;
>   *Тоді вся громада **буде могла** кожному забезпечити таке життя* — Iван Франко;
>   *Діти... **будуть могли** ходити до школи* — Іван Франко

---

Передмайбутній час зберігся у [сербськохорватській](https://sh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futur_drugi), [боснійській](https://bs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futur_drugi) та [сербській](https://sr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D1%83%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80_%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8):

> *Футур други глагола „радити“:*

```
Једнина              Множина
будем радио/-ла/-ло  будемо радили/-ле/-ла
будеш радио/-ла/-ло  будете радили/-ле/-ла
буде радио/-ла/-ло   буду радили/-ле/-ла
```

---

Передмайбутній час дещо схожий на **англійський** [Future Perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Future_perfect), і навіть включений в одну сторінку на Вікіпедії. На мою думку, це не зовсім точно, тому що англійська форма утворюється за допомогою дієслова *will/shall* плюс допоміжного дієслова *have* плюс перфектної форми (як-то *done*). Повна аналогія з українською формою була б, якби в англійській існувала форма *"shall did"*, або якщо б в українській була форма *«буду **з**робив»*, але таких форм нема.

Comment: Прекрасна відповідь! Якщо орієнтуватися на наведені в запитанні приклади.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko Дякую. Я саме тому і написав власну відповідь, що вважаю дві попередні відповіді не цілком точними. ;-)

Comment: Цілком погоджуюся з Вами! Я обгрунтувала, чому моя відповідь саме така. Бо я орієнтувалася на загальне формулювання запитання, а не на приклади. Ви - молодець! Але також згідна, що аналогії з Future Perfect не зовсім правильні.

Comment: @OksanaGubrenko, Так, непряме використання часів дієслова — це також цікавий аспект, і ваша відповідь розкриває його повністю. А у запитанні title — це моя правка (напевне, не зовсім вдала, але дещо краща, ніж була :).

Comment: Відповідь гарна, але із суттєвою похибкою - час не передминулий, а передмайбутній.

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо, Точно, дякую! :)

Answer (score 5):

Мовознавець Бондар Олександр Іванович захистив у 1999 році докторську дисертацію на тему "Система і структура функціонально-семантичних полів темпоральності в сучасній українській літературній мові".

Зокрема, у [авторефераті на здобуття наукового ступеня доктора філологічних наук](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:lNKjr5DneagJ:library.nuft.edu.ua/ebook/file/10.02.01bon%2520%25D0%259E.%25D0%2598.pdf+&cd=1&hl=uk&ct=clnk&gl=ua), знаходимо:

> **Вживання форм минулого часу у функції майбутнього пов’язане з уявним перенесенням майбутньої дії в минуле, майбутня дія, при цьому,
>   уявляється як вже здійснена.** Минулий “наміченої” дії в минулому
>   характеризується не переносним, а відносним вживанням форм минулого
>   НВ. **Форми минулого можуть вживатися у таких вторинних функціях,
>   транспонуючись у зону майбутнього**:
>
> 1) praeteritum propheticum, що вказує на близьке майбутнє або негайне
>   теперішнє (*Ну, я **пішов***) і обмежується дієсловами руху;
>
> 2) неминучий майбутній, коли форма минулого вказує на майбутню дію, в
>   настанні якої мовець цілком переконаний і сприймає її як наслідок
>   іншої дії, що вже відбулася чи може відбутися (*Взагалі, [Давид]
>   чоловік обережний. Немов що – **пропали** вважай* (А.Головко)),
>   обмежується дієсловами із значенням загибелі.
>
> Варіантом розглядуваної є функція неможливості майбутньої дії, що
>   трапляється в текстах усної народної творчості (*Ой бодай же ти, та
>   дівчинонько, Тоді заміж **пішла**, Як у степу та при дорозі Яра рута
>   **зійшла***);
>
> 3) допустовий майбутній вказує на майбутню дію, що сприймається не як
>   неминуча, а як імовірна серед інших варіантів дії для аналізу можливих
>   наслідків (*Гаразд, [припустимо] я **придбав** ваші акції, що далі*?);
>
> 4) функція іронічного заперечення майбутньої дії реалізується в КС із
>   непрямими мовленнєвими актами і супроводжується одночасною
>   транспозицією афірмативності в негативність (*Так він тобі й
>   **сказав** правду = Він тобі не скаже правди*).
>
> Вторинні функції минулого жорстко обмежені типом КС, а нерідко навіть
>   лексико-семантичною групою дієслів (**неминучий майбутній, близький
>   майбутній**).

Comment: Гм, а де тут йдеться про форму із запитання (*«будем їли»*, *«будуть купляли»* тощо)? Яка з форм дієслова у наведеній статті відповідає формі дієслова із запитання?

Comment: @bytebuster, на мою скромну  думку, по суті підходить третій варіант - допустовий майбутній. А форма комбінована, частина від майбутнього (допоміжнє *бути*) + форма минулого часу основного дієслова, - для привернення уваги і підсилення іронічного ефекту. Та й власне питання не достатньо чітко сформульовано, щоб можна було однозначно зрозуміти.

Comment: Тобто, третій варіант можна викласти у формі *«Гаразд, припустимо, я **буду придбавав** ваші акції, що далі?»* — вірно? Зауважте, у запитанні йдеться про «буду» + недоконана форма.

Comment: @bytebuster, я не зовсім це мала увазі. Бондар не розрізняє (принаймні у цитованій роботі) між формами творення майбутнього (проста/складна), а також між видами дієслів (доконаним/недоконаним). Він зауважує, що форми минулого часу можуть вживатися для позначення майбутніх дій. А в автора запитання в заголовку запитання теж ця диференціація не прослідковується, а саме так і звучить, ба більше, повторюється у першому реченні. Наведені приклади не свідчать, що автор запитував саме і тільки про таку гібридну комбінацію часових форм. Я зрозуміла в загальному сенсі, тому така  відповідь.